# Send and get data with socket.io with an other javascript file nodejs and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express

Lets say I have a JavaScript file that needs to communicate with other JavaScript file. So I could use this data in different javascript file.

In this case I have a `game_server.js`. In the `gameserver.js` I have two variables which I would like to use in the `gamecore.js`

```
var host // host of the game
var client // client that had joined the game
```

I would like to send them to the socket.io in de app.js and then use this variables in the `game_core.js`. So I can have data about the host and the client.

In the gamecore class i would like to have something like this

```
game_core.prototype.getPlayerInformation = function(data) {
    this.host = data.host
    this.client = data.client
}
```

It is all about getting information from the serverside to the clientside and the best way to do it is trough socket.io but i really don't know how

Also in the game_server script there is a instance for a game

game_server.createGame = function(player) {

```
   //Create a new game instance
   var thegame = {
       id : UUID(),                //generate a new id for the game
       player_host:player,         //so we know who initiated the game
       player_client:null,         //nobody else joined yet, since its new
       player_count:1              //for simple checking of state
   };
```

In the `game_core` the instance of a game is declared

```
var game_core = function(game_instance) {
    //Store the instance, if any
    this.instance = game_instance;
}
```

So it should be possible to get the `player_host` and `player_client`?

Answer (score 1):

server.js

```
var app = require('express')()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(80);

var Game_core = function(){}
Game_core.prototype.getPlayerInformation = function(data)
{
  this.host = data.host
  this.client = data.client
  return {host: this.host, client: this.client}
}

var game_core = new Game_core()

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.emit('login', game_core.getPlayerInformation);

});
```

client.js

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('login', function(data){
     console.log(data); // {host: xx, client: xx}
  })

</script>
```

Comment: I get everytime undefined isn't that because i don't get the neccesary data from the game_server.js

Comment: neccesary data? can you get another data? or nothing.i think build connection with game_clients is the point.